# Reuse controller paths for a Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, controller, dry

We have a Person class and in our Spring boot Controller for the Person class we have a few functions that have a path that starts with

> /person/{id}

However, we want to reuse all those functions for other paths where a Person Object can be retrieved like for example:

> /payment/{id}/payer 
> /payment/{id}/receiver

Otherwise, we need to write the functionality for GetMapping(path = "[...]/first-name") a lot of times. Is there a way to achieve this?

To clarify: For these three URL's it should execute:

```java
// person = the Person Object that would normally be returned
return person.getFirstName();
```

Comment: The actual logic for retreiving the person can just be reused in all endpoints. Maybe I don't understand?

Comment: Whats the point in having 3 endpoints which do the same?

Comment: They all reference different Person instances. So all persons are reachable via /person/{id} with {id} being their id. But A payment also links to two people. The payer and the receiver. I want to be able to use these methods without needing to retrieve the id via the payment/{id}/payer method and then use it on the person/{id} method

Comment: I don't understand, if there al instances of Person and can be retrieved with the id. 
What does the endpoint /payment/{id}/payer do differently than /person/{id}?

Comment: It does nothing different. It will just be an easier way of accessing the data and/or functionallity.

Comment: If you want ease of acces, maybe try looking into graph ql. Having 3 endpoint which have the exact same functionality seem over engineer and not dry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/person/{id}", "/payment/{id}/payer", "/payment/{id}/receiver"})
```

Comment: This is handy in some usecases for me, however this doesn't provide a way to do the same operation on the Person Object that that link represents. "/payment/{id}/payer" and "/payment/{id}/receiver" represent a different Person instance.